# Selenium::WebDriver Listening to Wrong Port

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, selenium-webdriver, firefox-addon, ruby-on-rails-5

While Running Cucumber, `Selenium::WebDriver` is listening to `Listening on 127.0.0.1:4444` while cucumber is looking for `127.0.0.1:7055`. How to fix this issue.

I am running Firefox `Selenium::WebDriver` which I downloaded from

https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/.

Error

> unable to obtain stable firefox connection in 60 seconds (127.0.0.1:7055) (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError)

TIA

Comment: well you haven't posted any code that will allow us to help you so Your issue is 4444 is the default port ([Source](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/blob/release/src/main.rs#L96)) and you have not changed it

Comment: My Cucumber code run Selenium::WebDriver and listening to 7056. How can I make it listen to 4444.

Comment: Which part of code, do you want?